# SocketChannel failed to communicate with TCP server (Apache Mina) even though session has been created

Tags: java, sockets, session, tcp, mina

Im using Apache Mina to setup a very simple TCP server, it basically bind to localhost and has a Mina Handler to handle events:

public class ServerInstance {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    InetSocketAddress address=new InetSocketAddress(8085);
    IoAcceptor ioAcceptor=new NioSocketAcceptor();
    ioAcceptor.setHandler(new MinaNetworkHandler());
    ioAcceptor.getFilterChain().addLast( "codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(new TextLineCodecFactory()));
    try{
        ioAcceptor.bind(address);
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

and in the **MinaNetworkHandler** I implement the `public void messageReceived(IoSession arg0, Object arg1)` :

```
public void messageReceived(IoSession arg0, Object arg1) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("msg has received in session "+arg0.getId());
        if(arg0.getId()==new Long(1)){
            sessions.get(new Long(2)).write(arg1.toString());
        }
        else{
            sessions.get(new Long(1)).write(arg1.toString());
        }

        //arg0.write("we have "+sessions.size()+" sessions");

    }
```

I limit the session to only two in the TCP server by using a hashmap.

**If I use telnet in my mac, two telnet client can communicate successfully:**

[image]

However, if i use Java Nio's SocketChannel as a client, it fails to receive/send msg but the session will be opened(not created) if i open the connection, in my sample client, i use a while loop to check if the channel can read data to a ByteBuffer:

```
public static void scatterRead() throws IOException{

        SocketChannel channel=SocketChannel.open();
        channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.2",8085));
        channel.configureBlocking(true);
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        buf.clear();
        buf.flip();
        while(true){
            if(channel.read(buf)!=-1){
                while(buf.hasRemaining()){
                    System.out.println((char)buf.get());
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

However, it fails to receive msg(two clients, one java client, one telnet):

[image]

**as you can see even if I use telnet to send msg, in the java client console it logs nothing.
But the strange thing is, in the ServerInstance console, I can see the session for java client has been opened(but not created).

[image]

Comment: If read() returns -1 you need to exit that loop and close the channel.

Comment: but the why i did not receive msg from telnet client?